# How to use generateX509V3Certificate?

Tags: android, google-tv

Currently, I have made the project about google-tv.
So, I had found the sample source in google developer web site.
I found it and then I did clone the source files with git.

The source files name were anymotelibrary, BlackjackRemoteActivity and Blackjack google TV.
but didn't work.

SSLUtil.generateX509V3Certificate in anymotelibrary had error that java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.polo.ssl.SslUtil.

Why it didn't work? It is just reference code.

please reply my question. 
Thank you.

Comment: I soleved this problem. Just load the library about anymote.jar, bcprov-jdk15-143.jar, polo.jar, protobuf-java-2.2.0-lite.jar in blackjackremote folder.

Comment: anymote library have this four .jar file. I made userlibrary and include four library